# Order of holomorphic functions at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, laurent-series

I need to show ord$_p(fg)$=ord$_p(f)$+ord$_p(g)$ where $f,g$ are meromorphic functions on some Riemann Surface.

So I just need help clarifying how to set this up.

Could I start by:

$\space \space \space \space \space $ Let $f(z) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty a_m(z-p)^m$, $g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n(z-p)^n$

Then since order is the smallest $m$ or $n$ such that the coefficient is nonzero, am I allowed to say:

$\space \space \space \space \space $ From here we can denote ord$_p(f)$ by $m_0$ and ord$_p(g)$ by $n_0$

$\space \space \space \space \space $ Then we have $f(z)g(z) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_mb_n(z-p)^{m+n}$ Then does ord of this $= a_0+b_0$

My indexing gymnastics is not up to par. I know if I do the RHS it is easier, we have

$\space \space \space \space \space $ ord$_p(f)$ $+$ ord$_p(g)$ = $m_0+n_0$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Study the the cases $\operatorname{ord}_p(f),\operatorname{ord}_p(g)$ both $-\infty$, one of them $-\infty$, both finite and at least one of them $+\infty$ (where the function in question is the $0$ function).

Comment: ok thanks that's what I needed the cases!

Comment: By the way, you should modify the title to say order *at a point*. Otherwise, it sounds like something very different. Where did the $a_0+b_0$ come from? You could rewrite your product as $\sum_k (...) (z-p)^k$. What is the coefficient then?

Comment: I meant $a_{n_0}$, sorry, and I am not sure I understand what you mean by rewriting it that way

Answer (score 2):

Let $f,g$ be meromorphic functions ($\neq 0$) with orders $\operatorname{ord}_p(f) = m_0$ and $\operatorname{ord}_p(g) = n_0$ First note that $m_0, n_0\in \mathbb{Z}$ since meromorphic functions have at most poles as singularities. Then we can write
$$
f(z) = (z-p)^{m_0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-p)^n , \quad g(z) = (z-p)^{n_0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n (z-p)^n
$$
where $a_0, b_0 \neq 0$. It follows that
$$
f(z)g(z) = (z-p)^{m_0+n_0}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-p)^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n (z-p)^n \right) 
$$
i.e.$f(z)g(z) = (z-p)^{m_0+n_0}h(z)$ where $h$ is holomorphic and $h(p) \neq 0$. Hence $\operatorname{ord}_p(fg) = m_0+n_0$.

Comment: could I ask why it suffices for you to drop the negative $\infty$ index? and why the two sums can both be indexed by $n$?

Comment: Knowing that the singularitynis not essential allows us to write the function as a product of a rational function and a holomorphic function that does not vanish at the point. And the index $n$ is a dummy variable, it does not matter how it is called.